# How to check the type of a variable in c++

Tags: c++

I need a function to tell a variable is for example Integral or not.
a function that returns Boolean

Comment: Types are in general known at compile time, not run time. You can use a template-based meta-function like [`std::is_integral_v<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral), but it won't work quite like a regular function. What do you need this for?

Comment: I assume this is related to templates? Otherwise it wouldn't make much sense since you would *know* it already. A better question, IMO, would be your *actual* problem. *Why* do you think you need to know if the variable is an integer? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and also read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Could you exactly say how this 'std::is_integral_v<T>' work?

Comment: `std::is_integral_v<int>` is a boolean constant, in this case `true`. `std::is_integral_v<float>` would be `false`

Comment: @BornaBarahimi https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral

Comment: Are you looking for [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) ?

Comment: How do you get this variable? Where does it come from? An example of your usecase will strengthen this question.

Comment: @Borna It works as described at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral).  And they tell you that there, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap [std::is_integral_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) (or [std::is_integral::value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) pre C++17) in a couple of helper functions i.e. :

```
template<typename T>
bool isIntegral(const T& value)
{
    return std::is_integral_v<T>;
}

template<typename T>
bool isIntegral()
{
    return std::is_integral_v<T>;
}
```

Example usage :

```
int i = 0;
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << isIntegral(i) << std::endl;
std::cout << isIntegral<int>();
```

Comment: One could shorten `isIntegral<>(i)` to `isIntegral(i)`.

Comment: While this is the more correct of the two answers I'm not sure the helper functions add much benefit over the more idomatic `std::is_integral_v<decltype(x)>`

Comment: @Fibbles Neither am I, it's just what the op asked for so I figured that they maybe needed it for an assignment.

Comment: Yeh, that's fair enough.

Answer (score -3):

Use **typeid** to find a type at runtime.

```
int i = 3;
cout << "i's typeid().name: ";
cout << typeid(i).name() << endl;
```

Comment: Caveat with `typeid`: It will give you a unique identifier for the type, but it gives no guarantees that the identifiers it produces make any sense to a human. Worse, the identifiers produced with one compiler and version may not match with the output of a different compiler or version of the same compiler.

Comment: Interesting.  The question is in the title.  The reason is in the body.  Oh well.   -3 and the accepted answer is somewhat amusing.

Comment: Assuming the Asker isn't simply holding a string and is really asking how to test whether the string contains an integer not, I see this as a path to an answer if they have a template and a Pre-C++11 compiler.

Comment: @user4581301 It's still probably not a very useful solution; the result isn't `"int"` but some mangled name, and you need to go through string operations to decode it. It would probably be easier to write `is_integral<T>` without `typeid`, with the bonus that the calculations would happen at compile time.

Comment: The answer is useless because it does not provide a function that returns a bool as asked for in the question. You can't even use `typeid` to make a function that returns a bool since the type_info of `int` is not equivalent to the type_info of `char` yet both are integrals.

Comment: As I said, the start of an answer. The rest is a series of `if`s, one for each integral type compared against the unknown variable. `==` doesn't give a crap whether the the human can read it or not. The real problem here is with a poorly defined question.